# jsonBody array only one index

Tags: android, android-volley

```
ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<>();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PaymentActivity.this);
    String url = backendUrl+"/api/orders/createorder";

    for(PModel pModel: pModels){
        products.add(pModel.toString());
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "createOrder: products array size"+products.size());

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("products", products);
        jsonBody.put("totalprice", convertFloat((float) totalCostDouble));
        jsonBody.put("productsprice", convertFloat((float) productCostDouble));
        jsonBody.put("shippingprice", convertFloat((float) shippingCostInt));
        jsonBody.put("tax", convertFloat((float) TAX));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, jsonBody,
            response -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "createOrder: response"+response);
            }, error -> {alertDialog.dismiss();
        VolleyLog.e("JSONPost", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    });

    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    queue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

I'm using volley to post data into my backend, the problem is I have an array of "Products" but when I check my mongo DB I get only one index which contains all of the products even though I get size 3 in the `Log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
JSONArray productArray = new JSONArray(products);
jsonBody.put("products", productArray.toString());
```

Comment: it makes me wonder, if that `.toString()` is required, whether or not.

Comment: dk, i use retrofit now.. :p @MartinZeitler

Comment: mapping by annotations is indeed more convenient, especially when it gets complex.

Comment: @SantanuSur same problem

Comment: can you post your expected json model ? for backend ? and also what you are getting now.. @SimpleWebDesigner

Answer (score 0):

try to cast that `ArrayList` alike:

```
jsonBody.put("products", (Object) products);
```

or alike:

```
jsonBody.put("products", new JSONArray(products));
```